# How to search for a specific pattern in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

Im having trouble with my query in Meteor since I am not quite well versed with MongoDB.

This here is a sample collection with two documents.

```
Ducks: 
[{
   name: "duck1"
   metadata: {
       id: "id_1",
       category: "samecategory"
   }
},
{
   name: "daffy"
   metadata: {
       id: "id_2",
       category: "samecategory"
   }
}]
```

I implemented a search functionality from atmosphere. What I want to achieve is that when I search for example: `d` the results will be both ducks. `du` will be only be `duck1` and naturally `da` will only be daffy. Also so that they will be filtered by the same category.

```
"$and": [{"name": {}}, {"metadata.category": "samecategory"}]
```

Inside the name `{}` is where the search queries. It will only give me the result when the name is exact. I can't find in the mongo docs if it has `contains` like in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will return a subset of documents which names start with `d` and have `metadata.category` set to `samecategory`:

```
Ducks.find({"metadata.category": "samecategory", "name": /^d/});
```

The regular expression `/^d/` is similar to `LIKE 'd%'`.

Comment: you can use regex in mongo?

Comment: sure you can. Keep in mind about performance too. Also there are text queries available in mongodb.